# StackExchange Data Dump user tags

Tags: tags, stackexchange, data-dump

For my project I am using the StackExchange Data Dump that I found on https://archive.org/details/stackexchange.

To be able to do my work, I need to know what tags a user has used mostly (these are the tags you can find when looking on a user's profile page). However, when going to the Data Dump files, I noticed there is a file called User.xml so I was hoping to find these tags here but no I did not.

Is there a way so I can gather these tags for the Data Dumps? Or should I do it brainlessly by writing a small application that retrieves these tags by calling the StackExchange API with the UserId?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs on meta